# MUI Dialog rerender when Alert fade in and out

Tags: material-ui, dialog, alert, rerender

```js
    import React, { ReactNode } from "react";
    import Navbar from './NavBar';
    import Login from "./Login";
    import { useRecoilState } from 'recoil';
    import { loginShownAtom, signUpShownAtom, alertAtom, alertShownAtom } from '../../infrastructure/store/atoms';
    import Alert from '@mui/material/Alert';
    import Fade from "@mui/material/Fade";
    
    interface Props {
      children?: ReactNode;
    }
    
    const Layout = ({ children }: Props) => {
      const [isLoginShown, setIsLoginShown] = useRecoilState(loginShownAtom);
      const [isAlertShown, setIsAlertShown] = useRecoilState(alertShownAtom);
      const [alertData] = useRecoilState(alertAtom);
    
      return (
        <LayoutWrap>
          <Navbar />
          {children}
          <Login open={isLoginShown} handleClose={() => { setIsLoginShown(false); }} />
          
          <Fade in={isAlertShown}
            addEndListener={() => {
              setTimeout(() => {
                setIsAlertShown(false);
              }, 3000);
            }}>
            <Alert severity="success"
                sx={{position: 'fixed', right: '20px', bottom: '20px', zIndex: '1301'}}
                onClose={()=>{setIsAlertShown(false);}}
              >
                <AlertTitle>success</AlertTitle>
              success
            </Alert>
          </Fade>
        </LayoutWrap>
      );
    };
    
    export default Layout;
```

so I have "Login", "Alert" these two components in layout.tsx

everything works fine until I try to show an error or success message with "Alert" after login.

When the "Alert" fades in, the "Login" component is re-rendered once, and when the "Alert" fades out, the "Login" component is re-rendered again, causing the screen to flicker twice.

I can't think of any state/dependencies between them.

F.Y.I. {children} seems unaffected.

thanks for your answer in advance.